# Building applications with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularJs and feeling very excited about it.
I've gone through basics and to get practical knowledge I
want to learning creating applications using angularjs.
Can someone please provide links where step by step guide is
given to build angularJs applications.
I've seen https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

But need some resource where more options are available
Thank you very much

Comment: Start building something...best way to learn

Comment: Do the course on codeschool.com it helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems you don't want to do google. BTW I faced the same problem you are facing now. I did google for the same and finally i reached on scotch.io and bennadel.com that helps me a lot. Hope these are also helpfull for you.

[scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tag/angular-js)

[Bannadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/recent-blog-entries.htm)

[Thinking in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

[Learn angularjs free](http://www.learnangularjsfree.com/angularjs/the-future-of-angularjs/10/1)

[10 angular js patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlvCbnKAH3g)

[How data binding works in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can learn angularJS in 60mins on bellow link.

[Learn AngularJS in 60Mins](http://fastandfluid.com/publicdownloads/AngularJSIn60MinutesIsh_DanWahlin_May2013.pdf)

You can also watch video on bellow link.

[Watch Video](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/angularjs-in-60-ish-minutes-the-ebook)

Answer (score 0):

If you love reading books, then you probably like this : https://www.ng-book.com/

But before you start learning, be aware about the fact:

1. Current Angular version is 1.3.
2. By year end or next year, they are about to release angularjs 2.0
3. Big thing about version 2.0 is that its not just an update. They are rewriting lot of stuff in it. Meaning, application working with version 1.0 probably won't compatible with 2.0. find out more about it here : http://ng-learn.org/2014/03/AngularJS-2-Status-Preview/

Good Luck :)